# Error after update adt

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

```
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\User\.IntelliJIdea12\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=5, Îòêàçàíî â äîñòóïå
```

What should I do to fix this one?

> IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4

Answer (score 0):

`Settings - Project Structure - SDKs change to jdk1.7 (was 1.6).` It helps for me.